# Writing toString() for an algebraic data type with parameters in Semmle QL

Tags: algebraic-data-types, semmle-ql

After reading about support for [algebraic datatypes](https://help.semmle.com/QL/ql-handbook/types.html#algebraic-datatypes) in QL, I'm trying to define a `List` type in the [lgtm console](https://lgtm.com/query):

```
newtype TList =
  TNil()
  or
  TCons(int x,TList xs)
```

This seems to work. But then I try to define [auxiliary classes](https://help.semmle.com/QL/ql-handbook/types.html#standard-pattern-for-using-algebraic-datatypes) in order to have a `toString()` predicate:

```
class List extends TList {
    abstract string toString();
}
class Nil extends List,TNil {
    override string toString() {
      result = "Nil"
    }
}
class Cons extends List,TCons {
    override string toString() {
        // what to put here?
        // I would like something like result = x.toString() + ':' + xs.toString()
    }
}
```

And here I'm stumped. I don't know how to refer to the constructor parameters `x` and `xs` from within `Cons`. I tried `this.x` and `this.xs`, but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I refer to constructor parameters inside a member predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Cons` extends `TCons`, you can treat `this` as an instance of `TCons` anywhere within a member predicate of `Cons`. This means that you can compare `this` to a particular instance of `TCons`, and bind variables to the constructor parameters.

```
    override string toString() {
        exists(int x, List xs |
            this = TCons(x, xs) and
            result = x.toString() + ":" + xs.toString()
        )
    }
```

Since you'll likely want to use the constructor parameters in other member predicates of `Cons` as well, you could instead declare [fields](https://help.semmle.com/QL/ql-handbook/types.html#fields) to capture the constructor parameters once in the characteristic predicate, and then use them in member predicates:

```
class Cons extends List, TCons {
    int x;
    List xs;

    Cons() {
        this = TCons(x, xs)
    }

    override string toString() {
        result = x.toString() + ":" + xs.toString()
    }
}
```

Just a reminder: As the QL handbook page you link to indicates, the syntax for algebraic datatypes in QL is still experimental and subject to change.